# Issues Splitting a String in Java

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I am having issues splitting a string by more than one parameters, the string that I must split consists of spaces, commas, a number sign, and colons. I'm attempting to split the string by each parameter but just coming across issues with stuff being printed more than once in the output since I am splitting the string more than once. I tried with arrays but that didn't work because it was only looking for spaces and not the other parameters. I then came across an idea to use delimiters which were going great till I ran into an error where the program would continue to run endlessly and not output anything. So the help I need is to be able to break up a String statement in a given format. Here is the input: **Clark, Ken, XL : Steelers,Pittsburgh : Ward#86** and here is the output I should get:

- Ken Clark
- XL
- Pittsburgh
- STEELERS
- Ward - 86

Here is my code so far:

```
public class NFL_Jersey_Order {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.println("Enter Order Information: ");
       //String name1 = scan.nextLine(); 
       scan.useDelimiter(",");
        
       String last = scan.next();
       String first = scan.next();
       first = first.trim();
        
       scan.useDelimiter(" ");
       String space1 = scan.next();
       String size = scan.next(); 
       //size = size.trim(); 
       
       scan.useDelimiter(" ");
       String space3 = scan.next(); 
       String space4 = scan.next(); 
       
       scan.useDelimiter(" ");
       String city = scan.next();
       
       scan.useDelimiter(" ");
       String space5 = scan.next(); 
       String player = scan.next(); 

 System.out.print(first + " " + last + "\n" + size + "\n" + space4 + "\n" + player);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out on my own, went back to using Arrays.

```
public class Order_2 {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.println("Enter Order Information: ");
      String name1 = scan.nextLine();
      
      String substrings[] = name1.split("[,:# ]"); 
      
      
      String team = substrings[7];
      substrings[7] = team.toUpperCase();
      
      
        
        System.out.println(substrings[2] + "\n" + substrings[0] + "\n" + substrings[4] + "\n" + substrings[8] + "\n" + substrings[7] + "\n" + substrings[11] + "-" + substrings[12]);
     
      
      
  
    }
}
```